# Google Drive Error with Shared Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have shared a [Google Script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-contacts-updated/27306/) with Public. However, the users keep getting an [error message](https://twitter.com/labnol/status/284184898443546624/photo/1) saying that too many people are accessing the file.

How do I fix this?

[image: Google Drive Error]

Comment: This needs attention of Google engineers. It seems like it is an intended feature but not documented anywhere.

Comment: Do you have the file open in multiple tabs anywhere? Beyond that @WaqarAhmad is right, this is a case for Google Sleuths.

Comment: @fooby This is not because of multiple tabs. As Amit Agarwal's app is being opened by thousand of user's at a time. You may check here http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-contacts-updated/27306/
Amit, Colud you provide analytics of the app so that we can have an idea, after how many users, this error comes.

Comment: Strange though, does this mean that the users are not making a copy of his script? @amit, would it be possiblt to publish your script as a library, and have users access that it way? Or do you receive the same kind of error?

Comment: seems like sharing code using something other than script.google.com would be preferable to publishing a workflow which includes opening your live files directly - at least until they offer a 3rd class of publishing (1. app, 2. library, 3. code share)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the current architecture of the script editor makes it so only a limited number of users can access a given script at the same time. We are working on some long term fixes for this limitation, and you can follow the progress on [Issue 2167](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2167). In the mean time, we recommend you use another method to share your script source with a large number of people.